# Python/Tkinter: triggering an event in the main app from an imported class module

Tags: python, tkinter

Following is code for a tkinter listbox, created as a class, and saved as a module named ModListbox:

```
import tkinter as tk
class Lstbox(tk.Listbox):
  def __init__(self,master,listname):
    super().__init__(master)

    # insert list
    self.insert(0,*listname)
    # place listbox
    self.place(x=10,y=10)
```

Likewise, following is the simplest code for a main app that imports the module and displays the listbox.

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()

MyList = ['first','second','third','fourth','fifth']

import ModListbox
NewListbox = ModListbox.Lstbox(master=root,listname=MyList)

root.mainloop()
```

In order to add functionality to the listbox, the obvious approach is to load the module and create an instance of the class, then to bind the listbox to a function, as follows, within the main application code. So clicking on the listbox triggers an event.

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()

# function on user selection in listbox
def UserClickedNewListbox(event):
    SelectedIndex = NewListbox.curselection()[0]
    SelectedText = NewListbox.get(SelectedIndex)
    print("You selected ", SelectedText)

MyList = ['first','second','third','fourth','fifth']

import ModListbox
NewListbox = ModListbox.Lstbox(master=root,listname=MyList)

# bind listbox to function
NewListbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',UserClickedNewListbox)

root.mainloop()
```

However, one reason among many that I'm creating tkinter widgets as classes is to keep as much code in the modules as possible, and reduce the code in the main app. So here is the same module, but with the binding and function included inside the module.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Lstbox(tk.Listbox):
  def __init__(self,master,listname):
    super().__init__(master)

    # insert list
    self.insert(0,*listname)
    # place listbox
    self.place(x=10,y=10)
    # bind user selection to function
    self.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',self.UserClickedListbox)

  def UserClickedListbox(self,event):
    SelectedIndex = self.curselection()[0]
    # How do I trigger an action inside the main app from here?
```

So now, inside the module itself, a user click on the listbox triggers the function. The function 'knows' the index of the listbox clicked by the user. How, if it is possible at all, would I trigger an event inside the main application, while also passing the selected index? Is this possible? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: You can pass the function as an argument (like `listname`) when creating the instance of the custom class and call this function inside `Lstbox.UserClickedListbox()`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying that I can define a function inside the main application, and then pass the name of that function into the class, in the same way that I passed listname?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: I would suggest to pass `x` and `y` as arguments as well because if there is more than one instance of the custom class created, they can be put at different places.  Or don't call `place()` inside custom class.